# Is a naturally radioactive elements on its ground state?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

Ground state is defined as the zero energy state. No energy can be taken from it. Still, radioactive elements can emit radiation. Do we consider them to be in a ground state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radioactive nucleus is not  in its ground state of course.   The state may be unstable, or metastable (which implies a slow decay).  Of natural elements, only iron-56 nuclei and smaller have lower energy than their fission
products.  This means that a LOT of nuclei are metastable (though the half-life might be VERY long) with respect to some kind of fission.

Light nuclei can go to lower energy by fusion, but that requires a second particle to combine with, so it's hard to call them 'unstable'.

Very heavy nuclei, including such items as neutron stars, are theoretically possible,
but I don't know much about their stability.

Answer (score 5):

Unstable nuclei are not in their ground state, but then, it's not clear that stable nuclei exist, at all.

We are currently searching very hard for proton decay: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay. A simple model has the proton decaying into a positron and two gammas. The positrons could then annihilate with the remaining electrons, leaving nothing but gammas at the end. Should it be found, then we will know that all matter that we can see around us is essentially just a metastable state and the ground state is radiation.

Comment: What do you mean that the ground state is radiation?

Comment: I suggest to remain in the SM, at least it is sure. As I know, on the SM, there is no proton decay, but still there is fusion/fission of "stable" nuclei due to to quantum tunneling, with extremely high half lifes. As I know, there is a nickel isotope with a little bit higher binding energy as iron, maybe it could be the ground state.

Comment: @peterh: The SM is the flavor of the week (pun!). To me proton decay is just as much SM as neutrino masses are or SUSY will be, if found. If you want, you can insist that we need to rename the model every time we add a term or two, but that's just an intellectually empty move to make yourself feel better that we have "learned something", when, in reality, we have just fitted another epicycle. As for the meat of this problem, it's not clear to me why the proton should be stable or why nickel should be the ground state. It certainly wouldn't be if Hawking radiation exists.

Comment: @CuriousOne Are you sure in the SUSY? I not. I am also not in the proton decay, because it would require a virtual particle with $10^{16}$ GeV, and maybe the $\Delta E * \Delta t < \hbar$ isn't valid in such a high energy.

Comment: @peterh: I am not sure about anything that hasn't been measured independently multiple times, but I am sure that the SM is just a low energy fit without much predictive power. We can make it jump pretty much wherever we want to. I looked at a bunch of the recent diphoton papers and those clearly show that the theorists will fit the model to whatever they are being given... even when it's just noise. That's a real problem. The proton decay is, at least, well motivated by question why any conservation law should hold exactly. I won't bet against it.

Answer (score 2):

They are metastable states, as you can see here:

[image: Illustrating stable, metastable and unstable states]

Comment: Stability though is related to being or not in ground state?

Comment: @Marion Yes - in a ground state, it can't decay anywhere. In the classical mechanics, the metastable states can be also permament, in the QM they are not.

Comment: Ok, this is what I mean, that a nuclei in ground state, at least in principle, cannot be radioactive.

Comment: @Marion Exactly.